# Lack of call signature - Array.prototype.map()

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm having a problem with the following code.

```
foo(values: string[] | number[]) {
  const mappedValues = values.map((value) => {
    return (typeof value === 'number')
      ? value
      : `'${value}'`;
  });
}
```

Typescript throws error

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<U>(callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[]) | (<U>(callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: number[]) => U, thisArg?: any) => U[])' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I've tried fixing it but without success. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

typescript is not sure on what types map has available since foo has two call signatures(string[] and int[])  it can resolve it in this example though

```
foo(values: Array<string | number>) {
  const mappedValues = values.map((value) => {
    return (typeof value === 'number')
      ? value
      : `'${value}'`;
  });
}
```

Comment: btw if you dont add type annotations for a lamda function you can drop the brackets around it : `map(value => {...`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I'm not returning an object. I have already updated code to be more precise.

Comment: could it bee that your conditino is reversed ? cause if its a number your returning it but if its a string you pacakge it in another string to return it oO I tihnk it doesnt like getting different return types

Comment: I have to to this like this. If it's a string I need to put it in single quotes.

Comment: and if you return the number as string as well ?

Comment: ah oh now I see it :o the foo functions has two different call signatures string[] and number[] thats where its gettings confused maype try Array<any> instead (or Array<String|number> might work as well )